# How to detect whether css floated items overflows to the next line?

Tags: html, css

When you use float:left or float:right, how do you know when a line has overflown to the next line? For example, I would like a collection of items to flow from left to right side of the screen at the bottom, but when the line overflows to the next line, just hide it. Is there a way to know at which point the float items overflows into the next line?

Comment: Check the height of the container the elements are floating in? If it changes after adding a new element then you've probably got an overflow. That or get the computed position of the floated elements. When the next element has a lower `left` it's wraped around.

Answer (score 1):

I'm planning on using jQuery to do something like this:

```
$("#container").resize(function(){
    var totalwidth = 0;
    $(".floatable").each(function(index){
        totalwidth += $(this).outerWidth();
    });
    if(totalwidth > $("#container").width()){
        // YOUR MANIP CODE HERE
    }
});
```

$.resize() fires at each step of the redraw in some browsers, so you might want to put a 250ms delay in there.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a way to detect this but you can give the footer container a fixed height and set it's overflow attribute to hidden.

Comment: Sorry but what I wanted to do was not hide the overflow, but detect when it does overflow and take action accordingly--hiding the entire line.

Comment: Same result (aesthetically anyways).

Comment: Oh sorry I think my expression was misleading. I meant hiding even the first line.

Answer (score 0):

One way to look at would be to

- Collect the items as per the float Order
- Calculate the total width
- Compare against parent and see if its greater.

Comment: Wow so I guess there isn't really a conventional way to do this. I was actually going to do this, but then decided to ask because I thought there might be a cleaner way.. oh well :(

Comment: or just try to put border to div and see how div look like when float.. :)